# How can i combine these two script codes into one indicator?

Tags: pine-script, trading, tradingview-api, pine-script-v5

i could not combine these two script codes into one. I tried every way I know but I couldn't combine these two codes. The first code identifies a channel, while the second determines the channel's midline. What I actually want to do is draw a third line that goes through the channel lines and divides the channel into two parts. Any help please?

First script is:

```
indicator("Nadaraya-Watson Envelope", 'NWEn', overlay=true,max_bars_back=1000,max_lines_count=500,max_labels_count=500)
length = input.float(500,'Window Size',maxval=500,minval=0)
h      = input.float(8.,'Bandwidth')
mult   = input.float(3.) 
src    = input.source(close,'Source')
showLabels = input.bool(false, 'Show ▲ ▼ Labels (repaint issue)')
lw = input.int(1, 'Line Width', [1,2,3,4])
dn_col = input.color(#39ff14,'Colors',inline='col')
up_col = input.color(#ff1100,'',inline='col')
//----
n = bar_index
var k = 2
var upper = array.new_line(0) 
var lower = array.new_line(0) 

ls = line.style_solid

lset(l,x1,y1,x2,y2,col,lineStyle)=>
    line.set_xy1(l,x1,y1)
    line.set_xy2(l,x2,y2)
    line.set_color(l, col)
    line.set_width(l,lw)
    line.set_style(l, lineStyle)


//----

if barstate.isfirst
    for i = 0 to length/k-1
        array.push(upper,line.new(na,na,na,na))
        array.push(lower,line.new(na,na,na,na))

//----
line up = na
line dn = na

//----
cross_up = 0.
cross_dn = 0.


if barstate.islast
    y = array.new_float(0)
    
    sum_e = 0.
    for i = 0 to length-1
        sum = 0.
        sumw = 0.
        
        for j = 0 to length-1
            w = math.exp(-(math.pow(i-j,2)/(h*h*2)))
            sum += src[j]*w
            sumw += w
        
        y2 = sum/sumw
        sum_e += math.abs(src[i] - y2)
        array.push(y,y2)

    mae = sum_e/length*mult
    
    for i = 1 to length-1
        y2 = array.get(y,i)
        y1 = array.get(y,i-1)
        up := array.get(upper,i/k)
        dn := array.get(lower,i/k)

        
        lset(up,n-i+1,y1 + mae,n-i,y2 + mae, y2 > y1 ? #ff1100 : #39ff14, ls)
        lset(dn,n-i+1,y1 - mae,n-i,y2 - mae, y2 > y1 ? #ff1100 : #39ff14, ls)
```

**The first code looks like** : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKXwE.png)
and **the second code looks like** : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxTJ2.png)

The Second script is:

```
indicator('Nadaraya-Watson Estimator', 'NWEs', overlay=true, max_lines_count=500, max_bars_back=500)
h = input(8., 'Bandwidth')
src = input(close, 'Source')
showLabels = input(false, 'Show ▲ ▼ Labels (repaint issue)')
lw = input.int(1, 'Line Width', [1,2,3,4])
col = input.color(color.new(color.white, 60), 'Line Color')
//----
n = bar_index
var ln = array.new_line(0)
if barstate.isfirst
    for i = 0 to 499 by 1
        array.push(ln, line.new(na, na, na, na))
//----
float y2 = na
float y1 = na
float y1_d = na
//----
line l = na
label lb = na
if barstate.islast
    for i = 0 to math.min(499, n - 1) by 1
        sum = 0.
        sumw = 0.
        for j = 0 to math.min(499, n - 1) by 1
            w = math.exp(-(math.pow(i - j, 2) / (h * h * 2)))
            sum += src[j] * w
            sumw += w
            sumw
        y2 := sum / sumw
        d = y2 - y1

        l := array.get(ln, i)
        line.set_xy1(l, n - i + 1, y1)
        line.set_xy2(l, n - i, y2)
        line.set_color(l, y2 > y1 ? col : col)
        line.set_width(l, lw)
        line.set_style(l, line.style_solid)

        if d > 0 and y1_d < 0 and showLabels
            label.new(n - i + 1, src[i], '▲', color=#00000000, style=label.style_label_up, textcolor=#39ff14, textalign=text.align_center)
        if d < 0 and y1_d > 0 and showLabels
            label.new(n - i + 1, src[i], '▼', color=#00000000, style=label.style_label_down, textcolor=#ff1100, textalign=text.align_center)

        y1 := y2
        y1_d := d
        y1_d
```

I tried something like below but it did not solve :(

```
indicator("Nadaraya-Watson Envelope", 'NWEn', overlay=true,max_bars_back=1000,max_lines_count=500,max_labels_count=500)
length = input.float(500,'Window Size',maxval=500,minval=0)
h      = input.float(8.,'Bandwidth')
mult   = input.float(3.) 
src    = input.source(close,'Source')
showLabels = input.bool(false, 'Show ▲ ▼ Labels (repaint issue)')
lw = input.int(1, 'Line Width', [1,2,3,4])
dn_col = input.color(#39ff14,'Colors',inline='col')
up_col = input.color(#ff1100,'',inline='col')
col = input.color(color.new(color.white, 60), 'Line Color')

//----
n = bar_index
var ln = array.new_line(0)
var k = 2
var upper = array.new_line(0) 
var lower = array.new_line(0) 

ls = line.style_solid

lset(l,x1,y1,x2,y2,col,lineStyle)=>
    line.set_xy1(l,x1,y1)
    line.set_xy2(l,x2,y2)
    line.set_color(l, col)
    line.set_width(l,lw)
    line.set_style(l, lineStyle)


//----

if barstate.isfirst
    for i = 0 to length/k-1

        array.push(upper,line.new(na,na,na,na))
        array.push(lower,line.new(na,na,na,na))
    for i = 0 to 499 by 1
        array.push(ln, line.new(na, na, na, na))


//----
float y2 = na
float y1 = na
float y1_d = na

//----
line up = na
line dn = na
line l = na

//----
cross_up = 0.
cross_dn = 0.

if barstate.islast
    y = array.new_float(0)
    
    sum_e = 0.
    for i = 0 to length-1
        sum = 0.
        sumw = 0.
        
        for j = 0 to length-1
            w = math.exp(-(math.pow(i-j,2)/(h*h*2)))
            sum += src[j]*w
            sumw += w
            sumw
            
        y2 := sum/sumw
        d = y2 - y1
        l := array.get(ln, i)
        line.set_xy1(l, n - i + 1, y1)
        line.set_xy2(l, n - i, y2)
        line.set_color(l, y2 > y1 ? col : col)
        line.set_width(l, lw)
        line.set_style(l, line.style_solid)
        
        sum_e += math.abs(src[i] - y2)
        array.push(y,y2)

    mae = sum_e/length*mult
    
    for i = 1 to length-1
        y2 := array.get(y,i)
        y1 := array.get(y,i-1)
        up := array.get(upper,i/k)
        dn := array.get(lower,i/k)

        
        lset(up,n-i+1,y1 + mae,n-i,y2 + mae, y2 > y1 ? #ff1100 : #39ff14, ls)
        lset(dn,n-i+1,y1 - mae,n-i,y2 - mae, y2 > y1 ? #ff1100 : #39ff14, ls)
        lset(l,n-i+1,y1,n-i,y2, y2 > y1 ? #ff1100 : #39ff14, ls)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```js
//@version=5
//credits to LuxAlgo for making both indicators.
indicator("(2022)Nadaraya-Watson Guesstimator [LUX] by LuxAlgo (dh remix)","(2022)Market Crusher",overlay=true,max_bars_back=3000,max_lines_count=500,max_labels_count=500)

//float length = 252
length = input.float(252,"length")
h      = input.float(8.,'Bandwidth')
mult   = input.float(2.8) 
src    = input.source(close,'Source')
up_col = input.color(#39ff14,'Colors',inline='col')
dn_col = input.color(#ff1100,'',inline='col')
updn_sty = line.style_solid, inline='sty'
mid_sty = line.style_solid//, inline='sty'
//----

n = bar_index
var k = 2
var upper = array.new_line() 
var lower = array.new_line()
var middel = array.new_line()

//Line Plot Function...
lset(l,x1,y1,x2,y2,col,sty)=>
    line.set_xy1(l,x1,y1)
    line.set_xy2(l,x2,y2)
    line.set_color(l,col)
    line.set_style(l,sty)
    line.set_width(l,2)
/////
if barstate.isfirst
    for i = 0 to length/k-1
        array.push(upper,line.new(na,na,na,na))
        array.push(lower,line.new(na,na,na,na))

    for i = 0 to length
        array.push(middel,line.new(na,na,na,na))
//----
//Set Vars..
line up = na
line dn = na
line mi = na

cross_up = 0.
cross_dn = 0.
if barstate.islast
    y = array.new_float(0)
    
    sum_e = 0.
    for i = 0 to length-1
        sum = 0.
        sumw = 0.
        
        for j = 0 to length-1
            w = math.exp(-(math.pow(i-j,2)/(h*h*2)))
            sum += src[j]*w
            sumw += w
        
        y2 = sum/sumw
        sum_e += math.abs(src[i] - y2)
        array.push(y,y2)
    

    mae = sum_e/length*mult
    
    for i = 1 to length-1
        y2 = array.get(y,i)
        y1 = array.get(y,i-1)

        
        up := array.get(upper,i/k)
        dn := array.get(lower,i/k)
        mi := array.get(middel,i) 
        
        lset(up,n-i+1,y1 + mae,n-i,y2 + mae,up_col,updn_sty)
        lset(dn,n-i+1,y1 - mae,n-i,y2 - mae,dn_col,updn_sty)

        lset(mi,n-i+1,y1,n-i,y2 , y2 > y1 ? dn_col : up_col,mid_sty)

        if src[i] > y1 + mae and src[i+1] < y1 + mae
            label.new(n-i,src[i],'▼',color=#00000000,style=label.style_label_down,textcolor=dn_col,textalign=text.align_center)
            
        if src[i] < y1 - mae and src[i+1] > y1 - mae
            label.new(n-i,src[i],'▲',color=#00000000,style=label.style_label_up,textcolor=up_col,textalign=text.align_center)//,size=size.huge)
    
    cross_up := array.get(y,0) + mae
    cross_dn := array.get(y,0) - mae

alertcondition(ta.crossover(src,cross_up),'Down','Down')
alertcondition(ta.crossunder(src,cross_dn),'Up','Up')
```

the length variable is limited to 252. as tradingview is limited to draw 500 lines.

Comment: Your answer throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

```js
//@version=5
//credits to LuxAlgo for making both indicators.
indicator("(2022)Nadaraya-Watson Guesstimator [LUX] by LuxAlgo (dh remix)","(2022)Market Crusher",overlay=true,max_bars_back=3000,max_lines_count=500,max_labels_count=500)

//float length = 252
length = input.float(252,"length")
h      = input.float(8.,'Bandwidth')
mult   = input.float(2.8) 
src    = input.source(close,'Source')
up_col = input.color(#39ff14,'Colors',inline='col')
dn_col = input.color(#ff1100,'',inline='col')
updn_sty = line.style_solid, inline='sty'
mid_sty = line.style_solid//, inline='sty'
//----

n = bar_index
var k = 2
var upper = array.new_line() 
var lower = array.new_line()
var middel = array.new_line()

//Line Plot Function...
lset(l,x1,y1,x2,y2,col,sty)=>
    line.set_xy1(l,x1,y1)
    line.set_xy2(l,x2,y2)
    line.set_color(l,col)
    line.set_style(l,sty)
    line.set_width(l,2)
/////
if barstate.isfirst
    for i = 0 to length/k-1
        array.push(upper,line.new(na,na,na,na))
        array.push(lower,line.new(na,na,na,na))

    for i = 0 to length
        array.push(middel,line.new(na,na,na,na))
//----
//Set Vars..
line up = na
line dn = na
line mi = na

cross_up = 0.
cross_dn = 0.
if barstate.islast
    y = array.new_float(0)
    
    sum_e = 0.
    for i = 0 to length-1
        sum = 0.
        sumw = 0.
        
        for j = 0 to length-1
            w = math.exp(-(math.pow(i-j,2)/(h*h*2)))
            sum += src[j]*w
            sumw += w
        
        y2 = sum/sumw
        sum_e += math.abs(src[i] - y2)
        array.push(y,y2)
    

    mae = sum_e/length*mult
    
    for i = 1 to length-1
        y2 = array.get(y,i)
        y1 = array.get(y,i-1)

        
        up := array.get(upper,i/k)
        dn := array.get(lower,i/k)
        mi := array.get(middel,i) 
        
        lset(up,n-i+1,y1 + mae,n-i,y2 + mae,up_col,updn_sty)
        lset(dn,n-i+1,y1 - mae,n-i,y2 - mae,dn_col,updn_sty)

        lset(mi,n-i+1,y1,n-i,y2 , y2 > y1 ? dn_col : up_col,mid_sty)

        if src[i] > y1 + mae and src[i+1] < y1 + mae
            label.new(n-i,src[i],'▼',color=#00000000,style=label.style_label_down,textcolor=dn_col,textalign=text.align_center)
            
        if src[i] < y1 - mae and src[i+1] > y1 - mae
            label.new(n-i,src[i],'▲',color=#00000000,style=label.style_label_up,textcolor=up_col,textalign=text.align_center)//,size=size.huge)
    
    cross_up := array.get(y,0) + mae
    cross_dn := array.get(y,0) - mae

alertcondition(ta.crossover(src,cross_up),'Down','Down')
alertcondition(ta.crossunder(src,cross_dn),'Up','Up')
```

Comment: Wait, what is the difference between this code and the code previously posted as an answer? **Please [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community.**